# Debugging from one solution to another

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have always wondered how I should do this. Lets say I have a solution A and a Solution B.
Lets say Solution A is the application I am working on. Lets say solution B is the framework for the application.

I have added the references of all the projects in Solution B in solutuon A. Lets say if I want to debug and someimes you may even want to step through the classes in Solution B, how is this possible.

I hope I have made myself clear.

Comment: It is possible on 2010 as long as the PDBs get copied; as for 2008, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build solution B as a library it will build dll's and pdb's for each project for you.

You can add references to these dlls in solution A.  The pdb's provide all the debug information for you, so as long as they're in the same directory as the dlls, when you step into solution B's classes in the Solution A debugger it should automatically find the source code for you.

Comment: based on your answer, I have another question. How do we build our solution as a library ?? Can you please elaborate these for me.

Comment: This is at the project level.  Within project properties you can set the application output type.  The main types are:
 1) Console Application: a program with a main method and an output console
 2) Windows Application: a program with a main method, but no output console
 3) Class library: a dll that other applications can use/reference

Comment: Thanks guys, I have figured this out.

Answer (score 0):

I add the projects (not the dlls) from solution B to solution A when I want to do this kind of debugging